# Shopify error: e.getBoundingClientRect is not a function (in widget.js)

Tags: themes, runtime-error, lazy-loading, shopify, partial-views

Please see the screenshot below for the error I'm getting:

[image]

Uncaught TypeError: e.getBoundingClientRect is not a function (in widget.js)

To reproduce the issue, I do the following in our unpublished Shopify Theme:

- go to cart page
- click on any image to go to the product page
- URL changes to the product page
- product page loads
- dev tools does NOT clear "Console" tab, meaning the page hasn't fully reloaded, only partially reloaded
- this error starts happening whenever I scroll up or down the page
- hitting F5 (force refresh page) reloads the page fully and this error goes away

We're using a Shopify App for reviews and it's responsible for the widget.js file.  The reviews load into the product page after a hard F5 refresh.  But they do NOT load in the case above, where you navigate to the product page from the cart page.

Something about this theme is causing this "lazy page load" behavior and it's causing our Shopify Apps to break.

I would love to preserve the partial load behavior, as it really minimizes page loading time by only reloading the product page HTML itself, but it's breaking the functionality of our Shopify apps.

My current thought is to put in a hack like this:

setInterval(function(){ /*detect URL change, then stop all processes and force reload page*/ }, 1);

But I don't really like this solution because it feels like a Band-aid that may not always work.  Instead, I think it would be a much better idea to fix the root issue, which I believe is in the theme code itself (hence the reason for sic-ing Shopify Support on this bug).

The current published theme we're using does not have this problem because every URL change results in a full page reload.

Has anyone encountered this issue before, and if so do you have any recommendations on how how to fix it?  I've already emailed Shopify Support and will gladly share their response here for anyone who's interested.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get rid of this error using pure Javascript to force a change in URL to reload the whole page using a cookie to record the last loaded URL, a stripping function to remove everything to the right of # and ? characters in the URL (so that changes in things like product variant would still use partial load only), and then a setInterval() to detect when the URL changed.  This seems to work well enough, although I can't help but feel a little hacky doing this...